# How to extract Text with Emoticons from an XML file?

Tags: regex, xml, twitter, extract, emoticons

I have an XML file with a lot of tweets and want to extract the text of every tweet which includes an Emoticon.

The XML file looks like this:

```html
<root>
  <tweet>
    <id>573890929636941824</id>
    <name>B&amp;BeyondMagazine</name>
    <text>Your Torrent Client May Be Mining Bitcoin Without Telling You http://t.co/xhTdmAYD20</text>
  </tweet>
  <tweet>
    <id>573890929628614656</id>
    <name>03/08</name>
    <text>@8900Princess that's what I thought you was on off the rip , that's why I said why &#128514;</text>
  </tweet>
</root>
```

So I need every text-tag value with an emoticon.

I would usually try to use a Regular Expression to identify the strings with Emoticons, but I read that you can't use RegEx with XML files.

How can I do that with an XML Parser (which one) or should I maybe extract all the tweets and use RegEx?

And after that I would have to extract all the Emoticons and count all the different types, any advice on that would be appreciated, too.